# How to send data to other participant on Room creation in Real-time Multiplayer Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, real-time, host, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am developing an android application in which I integrated the Real-time Multiplayer of Google Play Game Services. Everything is working well, but I still need to send unified value between all the participants before the beginning of the game (in Quickplay and when a user invites other players to a room)... I read in the "Real-time Multiplayer of Google Play Game Services" docs that a user can be choosen as the host of the game, but how can I do so and how can send these data to other participants before the beginning of the Game??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your own logic for this. The gps just sets up the peer-to-peer connection for you. After that it calls the onRoomConnected() callback.

This should be the point you decide which client should be your "host". You could do this by the random by choosing it depending on the clients ID, eg the "greatest" ID is the server, cause the ID is known for all clients and there is no communication needed, to find out who is the "host" on every device. If you want another logic for this, you could have every client calculate some value, send it to the others and decide from these values.